# Google Cloud Dataproc configuration issues

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, lda, google-cloud-dataproc

I've been encountering various issues in some Spark LDA topic modeling (mainly disassociation errors at seemingly random intervals)  I've been running, which I think mainly have to do with insufficient memory allocation on my executors. This would seem to be related to problematic automatic cluster configuration. My latest attempt uses n1-standard-8 machines (8 cores, 30GB RAM) for both the master and worker nodes (6 workers, so 48 total cores).

But when I look at `/etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf` I see this:

```
spark.master yarn-client
spark.eventLog.enabled true
spark.eventLog.dir hdfs://cluster-3-m/user/spark/eventlog

# Dynamic allocation on YARN
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled true
spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors 1
spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors 100000
spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors 100000
spark.shuffle.service.enabled true
spark.scheduler.minRegisteredResourcesRatio 0.0

spark.yarn.historyServer.address cluster-3-m:18080
spark.history.fs.logDirectory hdfs://cluster-3-m/user/spark/eventlog

spark.executor.cores 4
spark.executor.memory 9310m
spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead 930

# Overkill
spark.yarn.am.memory 9310m
spark.yarn.am.memoryOverhead 930

spark.driver.memory 7556m
spark.driver.maxResultSize 3778m
spark.akka.frameSize 512

# Add ALPN for Bigtable
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions -Xbootclasspath/p:/usr/local/share/google/alpn/alpn-boot-8.1.3.v20150130.jar
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions -Xbootclasspath/p:/usr/local/share/google/alpn/alpn-boot-8.1.3.v20150130.jar
```

But these values don't make much sense. Why use only 4/8 executor cores? And only 9.3 / 30GB RAM? My impression was that all this config was supposed to be handled automatically, but even my attempts at manual tweaking aren't getting me anywhere.

For instance, I tried launching the shell with:

```
spark-shell --conf spark.executor.cores=8 --conf spark.executor.memory=24g
```

But then this failed with

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Required executor memory (24576+930 MB) is above the max threshold (22528 MB) of this cluster! Please increase the value of 'yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb'.
```

I tried changing the associated value in `/etc/hadoop/conf/yarn-site.xml`, to no effect. Even when I try a different cluster setup (e.g.  using executors with 60+ GB RAM) I end up with the same problem. For some reason the max threshold remains at 22528MB.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here, or is this is a problem with Google's automatic configuration?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are some known issues with default memory configs in clusters where the master machine type is different from the worker machine type, though in your case that doesn't appear to be the main issue.

When you saw the following:

```
spark.executor.cores 4
spark.executor.memory 9310m
```

this actually means that each worker node will run 2 executors, and each executor will utilize 4 cores such that all 8 cores are indeed used up on each worker. This way, if we give the AppMaster half of one machine, the AppMaster can successfully be packed next to an executor.

The amount of memory given to NodeManagers needs to leave some overhead for the NodeManager daemon itself, and misc. other daemon services such as the DataNode, so ~80% is left for NodeManagers. Additionally, allocations must be a multiple of the minimum YARN allocation, so after flooring to the nearest allocation multiple, that's where the 22528MB comes from for n1-standard-8.

If you add workers that have 60+ GB of RAM, then as long as you use a master node of the same memory size then you *should* be seeing a higher max threshold number.

Either way, if you're seeing OOM issues, then it's not so much the memory per-executor that matters the most, but rather the memory per-task. And if you are increasing `spark.executor.cores` at the same time as `spark.executor.memory`, then the memory per-task isn't actually being increased, so you won't really be giving more headroom to your application logic in that case; Spark will use `spark.executor.cores` to determine the number of concurrent tasks to run in the same memory space.

To actually get more memory per *task*, you should mostly try:

1. Use n1-highmem-* machine types
2. Try **reducing** spark.executor.cores while leaving spark.executor.memory the same
3. Try increasing spark.executor.memory while leaving spark.executor.cores the same

If you do (2) or (3) above then you'll indeed be leaving cores idle compared to the default config which tries to occupy all cores, but that's really the only way to get more memory per-task aside from going to `highmem` instances.

Comment: Ahhh, this is really helpful. Need to do some confirmation that this is indeed is the problem, and will accept the answer if so. Didn't realize you could have multiple executors on the same node, so this makes much more sense now.

Comment: And I'm fairly certain that memory issues are the problem here, but Spark error stacks are often less than clear. I've basically been running a series of LDA topic models, with increasing numbers of topics (more topics -> more failures), so memory seems the likely culprit.

Comment: Yeah, executor sizing is one of those known confusing points of Spark, and unfortunately it's difficult to have good one-size-fits-all configs; [this Cloudera blog post](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/) has more details about implications of executor sizing.

Comment: In the case of using larger executors with more memory but also more cores, it can hide memory-limit issues at times if the packing of tasks gets lucky so that many small tasks get packed next to a single memory-hog task, but then it'll run into scaling issues when the total number of concurrent tasks is high enough that you more frequently trigger cases of packing multiple memory-hog tasks on the same executor. So in general it's good to have the memory-per-task ratio work for the 1 core per executor case, and then try larger executors to reduce overhead

Comment: Ok, so long story short, I should be increasing my ration of memory to cores, not scaling both in conjunction. And assuming I have the same machine type for master and workers, I shouldn't have to do any manual configuration right? And this is mildly off topic, but the rule of thumb for repartitioning RDDs to maximize performance is ~4 partitions per core, correct?

Comment: Correct, no manual configuration should be necessary if master/worker machine types are the same (and if they mismatch, the YARN setup still generally works and fills up workers, just that default values will either hit erroneous threshold checks or will chop nodes into a larger number of smaller executors than intended). And to increase your ratio of memory to cores, it's of course best to do it by going to highmem instances to not strand cores, and then second-best is reduce spark.executor cores.

Comment: Raising spark.executor.memory is less ideal because YARN does resource packing foremost by memory, not by cores, so for example if your executor requests 60% of a NodeManager's available memory then you'll strand the other 40% since no other executors of size == 60% can fit on that same machine. 4 partitions per core should be a good starting point, though generally you'll also want to size partitions based on the data size.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97244/discussion-between-moustachio-and-dennis-huo).